# Ada83 'Address Representation Attribute

Tags: ada

I have a legacy application that I am updating. The end use requires that a particular compiler is used. From what I have seen, this compiler is not recognizing this code, and produces an error:

```
   Procedure Copy_Buffer (Source_Address: Address;
                          Count         : Natural   ) 

      -- reserve a buffer Source_Array with  a number of words to fit 
      Source_Array : Word_Buffer_Type ( 1.. Count );
      -- and put it at the same address as the incoming buffer pointer refers to
      For Source_Array'Address Use Source_Address;
```

It is producing an invalid syntax error on the two lines

```
      Source_Array : Word_Buffer_Type ( 1.. Count );
      For Source_Array'Address Use Source_Address;
```

The intent here is to treat the source data as type Word_Buffer_Type regardless of what type it might be for the caller.

This works fine when I compile it using GNAT with Ada83 compatibility. However, the target compiler doesn't like it.

I see that the way this was handled by earlier developers was to process the buffer in assembly language. I really don't want to do that, and I am asking if there are any other ways I might readily (without going through too many contortions) process the source data in place.

Comment: This syntax was not valid in Ada 83.  The Ada 83 syntax is `for Source_Array use at Source_Address;`.

Comment: Thanks. I have a third party doing the compile for me tomorrow. I'll pass that on and report back what the result is.

Comment: For reference, the Ada 83 LRM is on-line; for example, [Section 13.5](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-13-05.html#13.5).

Comment: @SimonWright I had the 'Address Use line fixed and that line seems to compile okay. I am still getting a warning which I think is due to the line before that. "Warning: Initialization for variable Source_Array ignored because of address clause." While I have that investigated (I have to do this thorugh someone remotely located), do you see anything that might be wrong with that line?

Comment: @ajb You might have some thought about my comment above. Thank you.

Comment: It probably has to do with implicit initializations.  I don't know what a `Word_Buffer_Type` is.  But if it contains an access, Ada says that components whose type is `access something` must be initialized to null.  But if you have an address clause, that may not be right, since you would possibly be stomping on existing data.  Another case would be a record component that has an initializer; normally, declaring the variable would cause the initialized components to be written. ...

Comment: I think the warning is just saying that GNAT is not doing the initializations that the language rules say it should do, because you might be stomping on existing data. In Ada 95, I believe that putting `pragma Import(Ada,Source_Array)` [in addition to the address clause] would be the correct way to indicate that the initializations shouldn't be done.  I don't know if Ada 83 has the same rule.  You might try putting `pragma Import` or `pragma Interface` on the variable to see if that makes the warning go away.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Word_Buffer_Type is just and array of integers. It doesn't sound like a serious problem. But the legacy compiler issuing the warning (not GNAT, GNAT is fine with this) keeps the target embedded system alive. I expect it to be mostly Ada83 compliant. If the code is compliant and the compiler is not, I have to do it the hard way. If the code is not compliant, I want to fix it first. It appears that the code is compliant.